# Using OpenNi after Electric

Tags: ros, driver, openni, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a pretty simple question I imagine but I want to make sure that I'm understanding things correctly BEFORE I get too involved.

I want to use the OpenNi drivers for a PrimeSense RGBD sensor, I'll actually use any drivers, but OpenNi seems to be the most supported.

The ROS package for all things OpenNi says that it is deprecated in Fuerte. It says that you should compile directly against the system dependency instead.

This is the part I want to make sure I understand correctly. **I should download and install the driver/library directly from http://www.openni.org/ and then link to those instead of a ros package?**

Also just out of curiosity, does anyone know why this package has become deprecated?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58963/using-openni-after-electric/) by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 549 on 2013-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure which page you are looking at, but:

- http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera
- http://ros.org/wiki/openni_launch

Are the drivers and easy launch files for using Kinect or Asus/Primesense sensor. I'm not sure it will work with one of the earlier Primesense SDK5 sensors as there were so few of them around I doubt anyone is testing against them.

Note: I've quickly fixed the docs so that the fuerte docs show for groovy as they should be *mostly* the same.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on 2013-03-23**:
Thanks for the information. I was looking at the fuerte version of this page: http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni